# The timestamp on a comment posted on Github says "commented in 1 hour"

Tags: github

I just posted a comment on a Github issue thread. The relative timestamp says commented in 1 hour. On hovering, the time displayed is 1 hour into the future.

[image]

I tried posting some other comments. I also tried editing an existing comment. They all have the same issue (On editing a comment, it says edited in 1 hour). Is this a problem on my end? If so how do I fix it?

Comment: Is your PCs timezone correct? If it is, try opening a bug report with GitHub

Comment: Yes, the PC time matches the internet time. I even tried making a comment from a different machine, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub's servers are on Pacific time instead of UTC and this sometimes happens when the time changes.  It could also be due to a timezone or time change on your computer, but in this particular case, it probably is not.